# modrewrite forbidden access file but also change homepage

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I use a `.htaccess` file rewrite to make a file forbidden to visit when it does not end with `js|css|jpe?g|gif|bmp|png|xml|php`. Before I added the last three line the application worked fine, but after I added it, the homepage directs to an Apache system test page. I can't figure why. The other router url is still ok.

I use slim router

```
$app->get('/', function() use () {});
```

and .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

#if other domain direct to,  redirect
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) http://www.domain.com/$1 [NE,R=301,L]


#remove index in url
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php/$1 [L,QSA]


#disable indexes directory
Options -Indexes


#forbid access file
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?domain [NC] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?domain.*$ [NC] 
RewriteRule \.(js|css|jpe?g|gif|bmp|png|xml|php)$ - [F]
```

Comment: Go to the error log to see what's the error. This makes it a lot easier to solve the problem.

Comment: I wonder if I did rewrite your question correctly, as the last rule does the opposite of how I read the question. I am a little unsure what you are trying to accomplish right now.

Comment: @Sumurai8 Thanks  English is no my mother tongue, please excuse any errors on that part